# Remove border on icons click menu

Tags: html, css

I successfully created a metro menu here:

However I have two questions/issues that I am having:

1. There is a border showing when click on the items and I don't know where it's coming from.
2. How can I add a title that centers on the screen w/o affecting the icons

[image]

There is also big space at the bottom of my menu so I want to make sure that it only shows the proper space between my menu. I added max-height on the body element but did not work. Any idea?

Here's my CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,300,700,900);

body {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
background: #ecf0f1; 
}

a{ text-decoration: none; }
h2 {  color: #fff; 
    font-size: 22px; 
    margin: 0 24px;
    font-weight: 300;
}


/*= ICON BOXES
--------------------------------------------------------*/

ul.icon-menu {margin-top: 16px;}
li.icon-box {width: 120px; height: 120px; list-style: none; left: -47px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 3px;}
li.icon-box.home {background: #2b99ce;}
li.icon-box.design {background: #24cccd;}
li.icon-box.coding {background: #9a639a;}
li.icon-box.shop {background: #c44745;}
li.icon-box.contact {background: #2d9a63;}
.icon-box h2{Museo500-Regular; font-size: 20px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);}

.icon-box a {display: block;}

i.fa {
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  color:white ;
  margin:16px 0 0 14px;
}



/*= TITLE BOXES
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.icon-box.home h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #2b99ce; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
        border-left: 3px solid #247eaa;

}

.icon-box.home a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.icon-box.design h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #24cccd; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #1da7a8;
}

.icon-box.design a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}


.icon-box.coding h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #9a639a; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #6d466d;
}

.icon-box.coding a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}


.icon-box.shop h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #c44745; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #9b3735;
}

.icon-box.shop a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.icon-box.contact h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #2d9a63; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #1e6b44;
}

.icon-box.contact a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}



/*= MENU ICONS
--------------------------------------------------------*/


span.icon { display: inline-block; background: url('../img/icon-sprites.png')no-repeat;  width: 32px; height: 32px; margin: 43px 40px;}
span.icon.home { background-position: 0px 0px;}
span.icon.aboutme { background-position: -36px 0px;}
span.icon.portfolio { background-position: -72px 0px;}
span.icon.blog { background-position: -109px 0px;}
span.icon.contact { background-position: -145px 0px;}

.icon-box a {
    padding: 120px;
}

.icon-menu i {
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px transparent;
    padding: 0.2em 0.25em;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
        transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
    }

.icon-menu li:hover i,
.icon-menu li:active i,
.icon-menu li:focus i {     
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
        -webkit-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears when you `:focus` or when the link is `:active`. It is for accessibility purpose. Use the following CSS to get rid of it.

```css
.icon-box a:focus,
.icon-box a:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

---

Removing the padding from there will get rid of bottom space and replacing them with `width` and `height`:

```css
.icon-box a {
  padding: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

---

Creating a `<h1>` or something and centring, you can use the following wrapper class:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,300,700,900);
h2,
i.fa {
  color: #fff
}
.icon-box.design h2,
.icon-box.home h2 {
  z-index: -999;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -ms-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s
}
body {
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  background: #ecf0f1
}
a {
  text-decoration: none
}
h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 24px;
  font-weight: 300
}
ul.icon-menu {
  margin-top: 16px
}
li.icon-box {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  list-style: none;
  left: -47px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3px
}
li.icon-box.home {
  background: #2b99ce
}
li.icon-box.design {
  background: #24cccd
}
li.icon-box.coding {
  background: #9a639a
}
li.icon-box.shop {
  background: #c44745
}
li.icon-box.contact {
  background: #2d9a63
}
.icon-box h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1)
}
.icon-box a {
  display: block;
  padding: 120px
}
i.fa {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin: 16px 0 0 14px
}
.icon-box.home h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #2b99ce;
  transition: all .5s;
  border-left: 3px solid #247eaa
}
.icon-box.home a:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}
.icon-box.design h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #24cccd;
  transition: all .5s;
  border-left: 3px solid #1da7a8
}
.icon-box.coding h2,
.icon-box.shop h2 {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -ms-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  z-index: -999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 120px;
  width: 120px
}
.icon-box.design a:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}
.icon-box.coding h2 {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #9a639a;
  transition: all .5s;
  border-left: 3px solid #6d466d
}
.icon-box.coding a:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}
.icon-box.shop h2 {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #c44745;
  transition: all .5s;
  border-left: 3px solid #9b3735
}
.icon-box.shop a:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}
.icon-box.contact h2 {
  z-index: -999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #2d9a63;
  line-height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -ms-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  border-left: 3px solid #1e6b44
}
.icon-box.contact a:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}
span.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(../img/icon-sprites.png) no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 43px 40px
}
span.icon.home {
  background-position: 0 0
}
span.icon.aboutme {
  background-position: -36px 0
}
span.icon.portfolio {
  background-position: -72px 0
}
span.icon.blog {
  background-position: -109px 0
}
span.icon.contact {
  background-position: -145px 0
}
.icon-menu i {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px transparent;
  padding: .2em .25em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out
}
.icon-menu li:active i,
.icon-menu li:focus i,
.icon-menu li:hover i {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out
}
.icon-box a:active,
.icon-box a:focus {
  outline: 0
}
.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}
.icon-box a {
  padding: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <ul class="icon-menu">
    <li class="icon-box home"> <i class="fa fa-home fa-4x"></i>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Home</h2>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon-box design">
      <i class="fa fa-paint-brush fa-4x"></i>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Design</h2>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon-box coding">
      <i class="fa fa-code fa-4x"></i>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Coding</h2>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon-box shop">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-4x"></i>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Shop</h2>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon-box contact">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-4x"></i>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="center">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h2>How are you?</h2>
</div>
```

**Preview**

It shows like this for me:

[image]

Comment: 2. How can I add a title that centers on the screen w/o affecting the icons

Comment: There is also big space at the bottom of my menu so I want to make sure that it only shows the proper space between my menu. I added max-height on the body element but did not work. Any idea?

Comment: @KimberlyWright I don't understand your second question. What title?

Comment: Refer to the image above. I want to add an h1 and h2 that is centered on the screen w/o affecting my icons. How can I do that? where should I place my html? Sample if possible.

Comment: .icon-box a {
 display: block;    
 padding: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
} DID NOT WORK. STILL HAVING THAT BIG SPACE.

Comment: @KimberlyWright Check my updated post and see if it still has.

Comment: #1 and #2 is ok now but #3 is not yet ok.  
.icon-box a { display: block; padding: 0; width: 120px; height: 120px; } DID NOT WORK. STILL HAVING THAT BIG SPACE.  I don't know whats happening.,

Comment: @KimberlyWright Reload and see? Can you show by image exactly where you are finding it? Coz I cannot see it.

Comment: @KimberlyWright I don't get that space. Did you reload the page and see the snippet? Mate, run the code again from the post, please? Don't use `overflow: hidden;`, that doesn't work.